# Excel VBA macro for opening files crashes without any error message

Tags: excel, vba, crash

for few years I've a macro somewhere from the internet which opens all files in selected folder and does something with them (changes something in all of them, merges them in one, changes column order etc.).

For some reason, with some files the macro crashes without any error message. One day it crashes, the other day it does not. It crashes on my computer, as well as on there's computers or it doesn't crash on my computer and it crashes on there's computers etc...

It crashes if there are 50 files in the folder or just two small files.

There is only way I can make the macro run till the end is to create a breakpoint on *Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)* and sometimes even on *Do Work wb*. And then I press just F5 when the macros stops on this breakpoint(s) and it does everything it should until it reaches the breakpoint again.

```
Public LastLine As Long
Public final_file As String
Public my_directory As String

Sub ProcessFiles()
Dim Filename, Pathname As String
Dim wb As Workbook


Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 Application.EnableEvents = False

final_file = ActiveWorkbook.Name


my_directory = InputBox("What's the name of the folder with the files?:", "What's the name of the folder with the files", "New files")
Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & my_directory & "\"
Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xlsx")

Do While Filename <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)
    DoWork wb
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Filename = Dir()
Loop

    LastLine = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.TransitionNavigKeys = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub



Sub DoWork(wb As Workbook)
   With wb
       'Here it does the tricks with each opened file

End Sub
```

Do you have any idea what can be wrong with this?
Thank you

Comment: You should comment out, by adding an `'`in front of the lines, application.screenupdating, application.displayalerts. This will make excel show any messages there are, and could help you identify the problems at hand.

Comment: Try this - `Dim Filename As String, Pathname As String`

Comment: Replace `ActiveWindow.Close` with `wb.Close`

Comment: Excel files can become corrupt over time.  You should use  [MZTools](https://www.mztools.com/v8/mztools8.aspx) `Clean Project`  feature.  It will rebuild the project, removing any code residue that has built up over the years.

Comment: @Luuklag: No error message even if I disable these two.

Comment: @Vityata: didn't help either

Comment: @ThomasInzina: Not an option for me, as I work in a corporate company...

Comment: You could rebuild the Project by exporting all the code modules and then Importing them into a new Workbook.

Comment: You assign final_file but never avoid attempting to reopen it.

Comment: @ThomasInzina: Didn't help

Comment: @Jeeped: used it the Do Work part

Comment: Then you are still trying to reopen it.

Comment: Processing many files sequentially may lead to IO overload. Slow down your app with this: `Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds as Long):  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename): DoWork wb: wb.Close: Sleep (100)`. This will give the system a 0.1 sec delay to process IO. Might help. Test with different values, too.

Comment: @AcsErno: Did not help either :(

Comment: Have you tested this with longer pause? The situation when something runs well with breakpoints, but does not run without them typically indicates some overload that most probably happens at IO. I would encourage you to model the effect of the breakpoints by increasing the sleep time even up to 10 secs. I would also quickly test if the loop runs well without calling DoWork. Another possible troubleshooting approach is to reduce (comment out) instructions in your "tricky" sub, especially those that generate IO ops (.Open, .Save, etc).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation, that for no reason Excel would just crash without any error message when opening multiple workbooks in sequence.

Try adding `Application.Wait`
to your code after `Workbook.Open` and again after `Workbook.Close` - for at least 3 seconds. Haven't had the problem since.

```
newHour = Hour(Now()) 
newMinute = Minute(Now())
newSecond = Second(Now()) + 3
waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond) 
Application.Wait waitTime
```

I got this from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.wait